# Javascript statement for send keys

Tags: javascript, shell, vbscript, sendkeys, wsh

We have `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` `WshShell.SendKeys("1")`  in VBScript. Is there any similar statement to send key strokes in javascript.

Comment: If you want to use your javascript in a standalone application you would need to rename the extension to hta.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat it won't by default work in a browser, this will work using WSH;

```
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys("1");
```